# Unable to populate JqGrid footer with userdata information

Tags: json, jqgrid, user-data

I am having a tough time to display footer information using jqGrid. I have followed all the necessary steps to setup footer. The server request is based on some filter condition. The server returns a json with appropriate "userdata" information. Following are the JSON and javascript information.

```
{
    "timeatt": [
        {
            "empnum" : "12345",
            "name" : "ABCDEFG",
            "shift" : "1",
            "postdate" : "12/27/10",
            "regular" : "40",
            "ot" : "8",
            "dbltime" : "0",
            "holiday" : "0",
            "vacation" : "0",
            "payrate" : "0" 
        },
        {
            "empnum" : "67890",
            "name" : "HIJKLMN",
            "shift" : "1",
            "postdate" : "12/27/10",
            "regular" : "32",
            "ot" : "0",
            "dbltime" : "0",
            "holiday" : "0",
            "vacation" : "8",
            "payrate" : "0" 
        } 
    ],
    "userdata": {
        "name": "Totals",
        "regular": "72",
        "ot": "8",
        "dbltime": "0",
        "vacation": "8",
        "holiday": "0"
    },
    "totalrecords" : "2" 
}
```

jQGrid Information

```
$("#empinfo").jqGrid({
    datatype:'json',
    colNames:['Clock#','Name','PostDate','Shift','Regular','Over Time','Dbl Time',
              'Vacation','Holiday'],
    colModel:[{name:'empnum', index:'empNum', width:60},
              {name:'name', index:'name', width:200},
              {name:'postdate', index:'postdate', width:60,editable:false,
               hidden:true,editrules:{edithidden:false}},
              {name:'shift', index:'shift', width:60,editable:true,edittype:'text'},
              {name:'regular', index:'regular', width:70,editable:true,
               edittype:'text',align:"right", formatter: 'number'},
              {name:'ot', index:'ot', width:70,editable:true,edittype:'text',
               align:"right", formatter: 'number'},
              {name:'dbltime', index:'dltime', width:70,editable:true,
               edittype:'text',align:"right", formatter: 'number'},
              {name:'vacation', index:'vacation', width:70,editable:true,
               edittype:'text',align:"right", formatter: 'number'},
              {name:'holiday', index:'holiday', width:70,editable:true,
               edittype:'text',align:"right", formatter: 'number'}],
    scroll:1,
    scrollRows:true,
    height:300,
    editurl:'clientArray',
    footerrow:true,
    userDataOnFooter:true,
    altRows:true,
    onSelectRow: function(rowNum){
        if (rowNum && rowNum != lastSel) {
            $("#empinfo").saveRow(lastSel);
        }
        $("#empinfo").editRow(rowNum,true);
        lastSel = rowNum;
    },
  });
```

I tried everything listed in the jqGrid demo but for somereason, the "userdata" information is not getting populated. Can anybody help me ?

Thanks
SMargabandhu

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should remove comma before `});` at the end of your code. Your code is sure not full. For example `url` parameter is not defined so I suppose the comma come from the reduction of real code.

About your main problem. You should include [jsonReader](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aretrieving_data#json_data) in the jqGrid definition to be able to display the JSON data which you posted. The `jsonReader` can be following:

```
jsonReader: {
    repeatitems: false,
    root:'timeatt',
    page: function (obj) { return 1; },
    total: function (obj) { return 1; },
    records: function (obj) { return obj.length; }
}
```

After that the data will be displayed inclusive the `'userdata'` will be displayed (see [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Shanker.htm))

Comment: Thank you Oleg. Your solution worked. I wasn't sure about jsonReader. I am just a beginner and I was experimenting with every attribute. But thanks a lot for pointing out my mistake.

Comment: Hello Oleg, your solution worked when I specified the URL attribute. But in my case, the URL is empty since I have a filter condition and based on that I execute a function that makes a server call to get the required JSON data. Is it possible to set the footer row after I populate the jqGrid (addRowData).

Comment: @Shanker: Try to use `footerData` method: $("list").jqGrid("footerData","set",myUserData,true);

Answer (score 0):

the same name of the columns in (colModel) to return userdata, example:

userdata = new { hours= lista.Sum(x => x.Horas).ToString(), function= "Total HH:" }